# Installing Composer dependency manager and running it right afterwards

Tags: bash, php

I install Composer the PHP dependency manager and run it right afterwards this way on Ubuntu 18.04 with Bash:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
composer
```

A **two line** alternative will include `composer` in the second line,with `&&` or `;` like:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && composer
```

But I must say that by principle, I'm quite reluctant to use **one liners** with `&&` or `;`. Maybe I should just change an attitude, maybe not.

Is there an argument like `--install-dir=/usr/local/bin` or `--filename=composer` to also run Composer directly when installation ends, thus redunding the need for `&&` or `;`?

Comment: What’s wrong with the three-line version?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I just want to keep my installation scrips minimally-lined as possible and also running the program right after the installation as part of the installation in the formal way as a principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an argument like `--install-dir=/usr/local/bin` or `--filename=composer` to also run Composer directly when installation ends, thus redunding the need for `&&` or `;`?

Running `./composer-setup.php --help` lists the supported options, and shows that there’s nothing to implement what you’re after.

There’s nothing wrong with running separate commands, that’s what shell scripts are for. There is however a difference between separate lines and `&&`, which is that `&&` ensures that `composer` is only run if the download and installation succeeded. You can achieve the same effect with `set -e` (which comes with a number of caveats in some environments, but nothing applicable to you as far as I know).

If you really want to minimise your command line, you can run

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && composer
```

but I always recommend keeping a copy of downloaded installers.